# How to change the code to make new rows after x42 and y42 rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

This code creates two columns x42 and y42 data observations:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(rnorm(42)),
                 y = rnorm(42))
```

This codes change into horizontal the x and y as x1,y1,x2,y2... etc.

```
df %>%

  # cast `x` and `y` into long format:

  pivot_longer(c(x,y)) %>%

  # to each `name`...

  group_by(name) %>%

  # ... add the row number:

  mutate(name = str_c(name, row_number())) %>%

  # cast in wide format:

  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

I need to modify the code to make it stop at x42 and y42 points and start a new row x1, y2.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this? Are you sure that a dataframe with 2 rows and 42 columns is the best solution?

Comment: Also you don't need to call `as.numeric(rnorm(42))`, since `rnorm()` returns numeric output by default.

Comment: @Captain Hat I add example of how input and output would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
set.seed(123)

# I made the dataframe longer, because otherwise it's impossible to see what's going on 

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 y = rnorm(100))

w <- 42 # wrap value
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(x,y)) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0(name, row_number() %>% {. + 1} %>% {. %/% 2 - 1} %>% {. %% w + 1}), # 1 based indexing, folks
            group = cumsum(name == "x1")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 85
  group     x1     y1     x2     y2    x3     y3      x4      y4     x5     y5
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 -0.560 -0.710 -0.230  0.257  1.56 -0.247  0.0705 -0.348   0.129 -0.952
2     2 -1.27  -1.57   2.17  -1.51   1.21 -1.60  -1.12   -0.531  -0.403 -1.46 
3     3 -0.220 -0.236  0.332 -0.197  1.10  1.11   0.435   0.0847 -0.326  0.754
# ℹ 74 more variables: x6 <dbl>, y6 <dbl>, x7 <dbl>, y7 <dbl>, x8 <dbl>,
#   y8 <dbl>, x9 <dbl>, y9 <dbl>, x10 <dbl>, y10 <dbl>, x11 <dbl>, y11 <dbl>,
#   x12 <dbl>, y12 <dbl>, x13 <dbl>, y13 <dbl>, x14 <dbl>, y14 <dbl>,
#   x15 <dbl>, y15 <dbl>, x16 <dbl>, y16 <dbl>, x17 <dbl>, y17 <dbl>,
#   x18 <dbl>, y18 <dbl>, x19 <dbl>, y19 <dbl>, x20 <dbl>, y20 <dbl>,
#   x21 <dbl>, y21 <dbl>, x22 <dbl>, y22 <dbl>, x23 <dbl>, y23 <dbl>,
#   x24 <dbl>, y24 <dbl>, x25 <dbl>, y25 <dbl>, x26 <dbl>, y26 <dbl>, …
```